# Restrict local port access to a specific user

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall, access-control

I'm trying to restrict access to a particular port for a particular user on my Debian.

Let's say user's id is 1000 and port I would like to block is 5000.

I tried using iptables with the following command :

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 --match owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP
```

It works if the user does `curl 127.0.0.1:5000` or `curl <machine_ip>:5000` but not if the user execute `curl localhost:5000`.

I don't understand why it's not working. I though `localhost` was converted to `127.0.0.1`. What's the difference ?

In my /etc/hosts file, I have

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost   ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this after all this time and the accept/upvote =}

Comment: the same question with firewalld

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do the same for IPv6 ... localhost resolves to both an IPv4 and IPv6 address, and v6 is preferred.

Edit 1:

```
ip6tables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 --match owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this but I don't know how to do it for ipv6... `-o lo` in my `iptables` command should do the trick no ?

Comment: Try `ip6tables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 --match owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP` ;}

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much. I didn't know about ip6tables, I thought iptable worked for v4 and v6...

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: I did but I haven't enough point to make the upvote visible... :)